# Issue with first slide of bootstrap carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I've got a bootstrap carousel on my site.
This is the shortened HTML:

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="hp-top carousel fade" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="6000">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div id="first-slide" class="item active">

      <img src="" alt="Chicago" />
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <div class="carousel-caption-inner">
          <p class="slider-text small"><span class="slider-padding">What makes</span> us <span class="slider-green">specialists?</span></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">

      <img src="" alt="Chicago" />
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <div class="carousel-caption-inner">
          <p class="slider-text small"><span class="slider-padding">What makes</span> us <span class="slider-green">distinctive?</span></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I've created a function to make the text slide in a couple of seconds after the slide move.
This is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var carouselContainer = jQuery('.carousel');
var slideInterval = 6000;

jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
  if (jQuery(window).width() > 480) {
    function toggleCaption() {
      jQuery('.carousel-caption').hide();
      var caption = carouselContainer.find('.active').find('.carousel-caption');
      caption.delay(1000).toggle("slide", {direction:'right'});
    }

    jQuery('#myCarousel').bind('slide.bs.carousel', function() {
      jQuery('.carousel-caption').hide();
    });

    carouselContainer.on('slid.bs.carousel', function() {
      toggleCaption();
    });
  }
});
</script>
```

Now all works fine, however when you first load the page the last banner shows up for a second before the first banner shows.
I'm wondering if this has something to do with my function above.
Any ideas what could be causing this?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've defined a function inside of a condition within the doc ready. Don't do that. Move it outside the scope of the doc ready like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var carouselContainer = jQuery('.carousel');
    var slideInterval = 6000;            

    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        if (jQuery(window).width() > 480) {                    

            toggleCaption(); //replace function definition with call to function instead

            jQuery('#myCarousel').bind('slide.bs.carousel', function () {
                jQuery('.carousel-caption').hide();
            });

            carouselContainer.on('slid.bs.carousel', function () {
                toggleCaption();
            });
        }
    });

    //MOVED function outside of document.ready:
    function toggleCaption() {
        jQuery('.carousel-caption').hide();
        var caption = carouselContainer.find('.active').find('.carousel-caption');
        caption.delay(1000).toggle("slide", { direction: 'right' });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: If you're looking to speed up the first load of the slides, you should look at this bit here: caption.delay(1000) and either reduce the 1000 to 200-300 to speed up the load, OR, make the delay duration a parameter passed to toggleCaption(delayLength) and pass it as a lower value on first load (first call in doc ready above) with 1000 in the second call for .on('slid.bs.carousel') handler. Flexible.